# Regex issue in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, phpmyadmin

I cant seem to get the following search query to work in `phpMyadmin`.

```
 SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `content` REGEXP 'https?\:\/\/(.*?(?<!cgi\.)ebay)';
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
 #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

The regular expression itself works perfectly fine when I created it so not sure what is the problem, see here: http://regex101.com/r/qN2jX4/1

Comment: What's the matter with `SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `content` LIKE 'http%ebay';`

Comment: That gives no results. The ebay link has to be anything except cgi.ebay

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE content NOT LIKE '%cgi.ebay%'`?

Comment: That will not work because that table does not only contain ebay links with or without the cgi subdomain. It will give me all link types as well as useless text. It has to be something that tell to query something that a url and has ebay in it but does not have cgi in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

The `.*?` looks suspect as does the `?<`.  Removing the extra `?` fixes the error:

```
WHERE `content` REGEXP 'https?\:\/\/(.*(<!cgi\.)ebay)';
```

Perhaps this does what you want.

Comment: good one, tried different things and good to see the solution.

Comment: Thanks, this stopped giving me an error but gives 0 results. I cant figure out whats is wrong because I'm sure I have many URLs that look like www.ebay and more non-cgi .

Comment: I did some more research and read that MySQL may not have the negation operator "?!" ? Anyway, I tried another option but it also removes urls like i.ebay.com or anything with one of the threaa letters , not actualy the full phrase:   REGEXP 'https?\:\/\/[^(cgi|mobile)]*\.ebay'

Comment: @user1745382 . . . If you want help solving the real problem rather than the syntax issue, ask another question, describe the logic that you want, and give examples of `content` that you want to pass and fail the test.